# Elasticsearch and Kibana: aggregation to find the name of the most rewarded miner, daily

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql, kibana, nosql-aggregation

I created an index from a Storm topology to ElasticSearch (ES). The index map is basically:

index: btc-block

- miner: text
- reward: double
- datetime: date

From those documents I would like to create a histogram of the richest miner, on a daily scale.

I am wondering if I should aggregate first in storm and just use ES and Kibana to store, query and then display the data or if ES and Kibana can handle such requests.

I have been looking at the Transforms, in the index management section, that allows to create new indices from queries and aggregations in continuous modes but I can't succeed to get to the expected result.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can definitely accomplish this with simple area graphs in Kibana. What problems are you running into?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Well, I'd rather prefer an histogram, but it's the same principle. See my answer below, I think I solved my issue. Any thought about the philosophy according to the amount of data: aggregation in Storm or in ES/Kibana?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes we need to ask a question to find the answer...
I kept looking at the documentation and eventually I could solve the issue by using a sibling pipeline aggregation, in the visualization. In my case, a max bucket aggregation of the sum of reward on Y-axis.

In that case get like 6 records/hour so I guess it's ok to let Kibana and ES work. What if I got lot more data? Would it not be wiser to aggregate in Storm?